# Writing Truly Private Functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, module, functional-programming

I want to write a function that gives me control over what API's it can execute.
For example, how would I write an anonymous function that privately executes without jQuery after jQuery has been loaded into the page:

```
var app = (function(){
  $("body").append("should not append because it does not recognize jQuery");
})();
```

instead of

```
var app = (function(){
  $("body").append("should append because jQuery is recognized");
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There's no difference there since you're not passing an argument. Can you be more specific, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: this passes jQuery as an argument?

Comment: jQuery doesn't work like that. The `$` function is a global object. You can't hide it from anything if you include jQuery

Comment: You're not passing the argument `var app = (function($){`, but Nasser is right. Try using `$.noConflict`

Comment: so once jQuery is loaded into the page, it is recognized by all functions?

Comment: @Emanegux yes it is. Anyway, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to write a function so that everything that goes on inside the function is free from outer dependencies

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't hide global variables and objects in your program. But, since JS has function scoping, you can declare a local `$` and do with it whatever you want, without overwriting the global `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on what Nasser said, you can declare (locally) the things you want to disallow as undefined variables:

```
// allow jQuery
(function () { // don't overwrite $ or jQuery, so it's allowed, basically
    $("body").append("should append because jQuery is recognized");
}());


// disallow jQuery
(function ($, jQuery) { // declare $ and jQuery as undefined in the function scope
    // the line below will throw an error, though
    $("body").append("should not append because it does not recognize jQuery");
}());
```

You can further expand on this, but that's the general idea.

Comment: This works for jQuery but do I have to explicitly state what I don't want in order to run the function free from referencing anything outside it?

Comment: Also, why did you change the parentheses order from (function(){})() to (function(){}())?

Comment: Yes, you have to explicitly state what you don't want. That's JavaScript :) I changed the parenthesis just because it's my preference; both work equally well. There are several other ways to do it as well but all the same result.